# Isotope Masonry Grid Issue

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, html, ejs

I am working on a NodeJS project using Firebase as backend, NodeJs as server-side, and EJS + HTML + JS + CSS as the front end.

On my main screen I have a 3-column masonry grid for images that I am displaying; similar to pinterest. I also have an ADD MORE button at the bottom of the grid that sends a request to the api to retrieve more images to display on the page.

Approach 1:

I have 40 images.

In my route I will retrieve the data from Firebase THEN render the ejs view with the data. I want to load the first 20 images.
Pros: It allows all of my content on the page to have the correct styling and it works with the styling of the grid; if image heights differ, the grid layout adjusts the content accordingly.
Cons: I don't know how to handle pagination to load the remaining images at intervals of 5.

Here's an image: [image]

Here's the code snippets:

NodeJS:

```
router.get('/home', function(req, res { firObj.database().ref('igrushi/content').orderByKey().limitToLast(14).once('value', function (snapshot) {
    res.status(200).render('igrushiexperience/index', { 
        title: "",
        data: snapshot.val(),
    });
});
```

ejs =>

```
<div class="portfolio portfolio-gutter portfolio-style-2 portfolio-masonry portfolio-not-full portfolio-3-column">
                        <% var keys; %>
                        <% var lastKey; %>
                        <% if (data != null) { %>
                            <% keys = Object.keys(data); %>
                            <% console.log(keys); %>
                            <% lastKey = keys[0]; %>
                            <% keys.forEach(function(child) { %>
                            <% var value = data[child] %>
                            <div class="portfolio-item cat-1 cat-3 ">
                                <div class="portfolio-item-content">
                                    <div class="item-thumbnail">
                                        <img src="<%= value.post_image %>" alt="" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <% }); %>
                        <% }; %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pagination-area">
                        <div class="load-more text-center">
                            <a class="button" href="/events/igrushiexperience/pagination/<%= lastKey %>">view more<i class="ti-reload"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>`
```

Approach 2:
I have 40 images.

In my route I will render the ejs view, My EJS will contain a XMLHttpRequest to another node js endpoint that fetches the data. Upon fetching the data, I use appendChild to create the DIVs and add the items to the grid.

Pro: This approach allows my pagination request to succeed and continue to fetch and render the data at the 5 item interval.
Con: The CSS styling does not hold up and the grid does not adjust for the different heights.

Here's is an image [image]

Here's the code snippet:

html =>

```
<div class="portfolio-fullwidth">
                <div class="portfolio-content">
                    <div id="gallery" class="portfolio portfolio-gutter portfolio-style-2 portfolio-masonry portfolio-full portfolio-3-column">
                    </div>
                    <div class="pagination-area">
                        <div class="load-more text-center">
                            <a class="button" onClick="pagination(this)">view more<i class="ti-reload"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

js:

```
<script>
    var keys;
    function retrieveData() {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var posts = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                keys = Object.keys(posts); 
                keys.forEach(function(id) {
                    var post = posts[id];
                    addItemToGallery(post);
                });
                console.log(keys);
            };
        };
        request.open("GET", "/events/igrushiexperience/retrievePosts", true);
        request.send();
    }

    function pagination(e) {
        var keyForPagination;
        if (keys.length > 0) {
            keyForPagination = keys[keys.length - 1];
        } else {
            return retrieveData();
        }
        console.log(keyForPagination);

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var posts = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                var paginationKeys = Object.keys(posts); 
                paginationKeys.forEach(function(id) {
                    if (!keys.includes(id)) {
                        keys.push(id);
                        var post = posts[id];
                        addItemToGallery(post);
                    }
                });
                console.log("New Array: ", keys);
            };
        };
        request.open("GET", "/events/igrushiexperience/pagination/"+ keyForPagination, true);
        request.send();
    }

    function addItemToGallery(post) {
        var divOne = document.createElement("div");
        divOne.className = "portfolio-item cat-1 cat-3";
        var divTwo = document.createElement("div");
        divTwo.className = "portfolio-item-content";
        var divThree = document.createElement("div");
        divThree.className = "item-thumbnail";
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.src = post.post_image;

        divThree.appendChild(image);
        divTwo.appendChild(divThree);
        divOne.appendChild(divTwo);

        document.getElementById("gallery").appendChild(divOne);
    }

    retrieveData();
</script>
```

Help please

Answer (score 1):

Ok so after some research I realized that the project was doing a few things:

1) Asking the wrong question
2) Using Isotope (https://isotope.metafizzy.co/) to render the masonry grid
3) Appending elements incorrectly
4) Not re-rendering the grid after items were appended.

So to solve this, I =>

1) Reviewed the documentation -- reading is fundamental here, lol -- and I saw that the library had a bunch of awesome helper methods to assist with dynamically appending items to the grid.
2) Initialized the grid on window load and stored a reference of it into a variable so that I can reuse it later.
3) Created a method that handled retrieving data from backend and passed the objects into another function that used the Isotope specific helper method to append the html items to the grid. Below is the method.

```
var $grid;
var keyForPagination;
var httpRequestInQueue = false;

$(window).load(function () {
    $grid = $('.portfolio-masonry');
    $grid.imagesLoaded(function() {
       $grid.isotope({
           itemSelector: '.portfolio-item',
           percentPosition: true,
       });
    });
 });

function addItemToGallery(post) {
    var $item = $('<div class="portfolio-item cat-1 cat-3 "><div class="portfolio-item-content"><div class="item-thumbnail"><img src="'+post.post_image+'" alt="" ></div></div></div>');
    $grid.imagesLoaded(function() {
        $grid.append($item);
        $grid.isotope('appended', $item);
    });
 }
```

Per the documentation, append adds the item to the grid after the images have been loaded and the the 'appended' method lays out the grid after the elements are added the the grid.